# combine arrays if duplicate element is found in another array python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of arrays that go like:

```
[array(['A2', 'A1'], dtype=object),
 array(['A2', 'A3'], dtype=object),
 array(['A2', 'A4'], dtype=object),
 array(['A1', 'A3'], dtype=object),
 array(['A1', 'A4'], dtype=object),
 array(['A3', 'A4'], dtype=object),
 array(['B2', 'B1'], dtype=object),
 array(['B2', 'B3'], dtype=object),
 array(['B1', 'B3'], dtype=object)]
```

I want to combine those arrays if one of the elements in an array is found in another array. And then remove the duplicate.

The expected outcome should go like:

```
[array['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'], array[B1', 'B2', 'B3']]
```

Any idea about how I can do this?
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want the connected components of a graph.

```
from numpy import array

edges = [
    array(['A2', 'A1'], dtype=object),
    array(['A2', 'A3'], dtype=object),
    array(['A2', 'A4'], dtype=object),
    array(['A1', 'A3'], dtype=object),
    array(['A1', 'A4'], dtype=object),
    array(['A3', 'A4'], dtype=object),
    array(['B2', 'B1'], dtype=object),
    array(['B2', 'B3'], dtype=object),
    array(['B1', 'B3'], dtype=object),
]

import networkx
G = networkx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(edges)
print(list(networkx.connected_components(G)))
# [{'A1', 'A3', 'A4', 'A2'}, {'B2', 'B1', 'B3'}]
```

Demo: https://repl.it/repls/FluidPleasedScope

[networkx documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html#networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components)

Answer (score 0):

You can use, [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) + [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
from itertools import groupby
from numpy import array, unique

values = [
    array(['A2', 'A1'], dtype=object),
    array(['A2', 'A3'], dtype=object),
    array(['A2', 'A4'], dtype=object),
    array(['A1', 'A3'], dtype=object),
    array(['A1', 'A4'], dtype=object),
    array(['A3', 'A4'], dtype=object),
    array(['B2', 'B1'], dtype=object),
    array(['B2', 'B3'], dtype=object),
    array(['B1', 'B3'], dtype=object)
]

print([
    list(v) for _, v in groupby(unique(values), key=lambda x: x[0])
])
```

---

```
[['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'], ['B1', 'B2', 'B3']]
```